# Error "Client wants topic A to have B, but our version has C. Dropping connection."

Tags: ros, messages, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my custom application using custom message, publisher node show the following message only once on its running console when subscriber starts. Both nodes keep running but it seems nothing occur after that.

error msg:

```
[ERROR] [1319162712.616980036]: Client [/clientNodeA] wants topic /server_msgs/Swarm 
to have datatype/md5sum [server_msgs/Swarm/6a727e7bfd7e4aadf9d23c4a779b268e], 
but our version has [geometry_msgs/Point/4a842b65f413084dc2b10fb484ea7f17]. 
Dropping connection.
```

Content of the custom message (/server_msgs/Swarm):

```
uint32 clockValue
geometry_msgs/Point[] crowds
```

[Publisher node's code .cpp](http://pastebin.com/NCGRkbgw) (partial)

[Subscriber node's code .cpp](http://pastebin.com/uTGXLwBV)

Running environment: Ubuntu 11.04, electric

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11618/error-%22client-wants-topic-a-to-have-b,-but-our-version-has-c.-dropping-connection.%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your publisher *is* advertising `geomety_msgs/Point` (line 15).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-20**:
@joq thank you. This was my bad careless mistake...

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-01-30**:
Just to be clear (since this is the first google result for client wants topic to have datatype/md5sum), the error is that the publisher and subscriber on the same topic have differing message types.

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-03-13**:
I changed my custom message to have header in it. After that I keep getting this error.

```
[ERROR] [1552465010.096584454, 1550537307.791138420]: Client [/rostopic_21875_1552464987475] wants topic /3d_data to have datatype/md5sum [openpose_ros/PersonDetection_3d/bc1a43439603de5789cfba6300034ed3], but our version has [openpose_ros/PersonDetection_3d/a4ff6437cb65b2eb3d526e8df30d59ce]. Dropping connection.
```

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-03-13**:
Make sure sender and receiver have the latest version with the header (maybe both need to pull the latest source and recompile if on different computers), and that they have sourced devel or install setup.bash where the new version was built (restarting a terminal as mentioned below will possibly do that).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else who gets this error, check the queue size. I had this error, but in my case it was caused by conflicting queue sizes between the publisher and subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) with karma: 107 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tarunuday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30296/tarunuday/) on 2018-03-30**:
I had a similar non-obvious issue that went away when I restarted all of my terminal tabs. Using Terminator on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine